# Query optimization [Oracle]

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-tuning

How can I optimize the performance of this query?

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT DT.id) 
FROM   pcwdeptrans DT 
       INNER JOIN pcwitemtotal IT 
               ON DT.id = IT.deposittransid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN pcwdepreceipt DR 
                    ON DR.deposittransid = DT.id 
WHERE  (( ( DT.statecode IN ( :1, :2, :3, :4, 
                              :5, :6, :7, :8 ) 
             OR ( DT.statecode IN ( :9 ) 
                  AND IT.statecode = :10 ) ) 
          AND DR.requesttime >= :11 
          AND DR.requesttime <= :12 
          AND DR.userid = :13 ))
```

Please help me with the right syntax if you think its incorrect.

But this is an application query, identified from the AWR report as part of performance analysis

### Excerpt from AWR:

[Top SQL with TOP Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DAkz.png)

### Its Execution plan from test DB (prod will be different):

[Execution plan of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ktLO.png)

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is turning the outer join into an inner join -- if I'm reading the parentheses correctly.

Comment: I agree with Gordon. You should make sure your query is **functionally correct** before you start tuning it.

Answer (score -1):

Join together with Where can be slow. following could be faster (but not the same... see comments and rethink if you need inner or outer join...)

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT DT.id) 
FROM pcwdeptrans DT 
  INNER JOIN pcwitemtotal IT 
      ON DT.id = IT.deposittransid 
     AND ( DT.statecode IN ( :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8 ) 
       OR ( DT.statecode IN ( :9 ) AND IT.statecode = :10 ) )
  LEFT OUTER JOIN pcwdepreceipt DR 
      ON DR.deposittransid = DT.id 
     AND DR.requesttime >= :11 
     AND DR.requesttime <= :12 
     AND DR.userid = :13
```

edit:
The discussion whether it should be an inner or outer join was already started in the question's comments before. Transforming the question's outer join to a inner join with the where clause may or may not be intendet.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT DT.id) 
FROM pcwdeptrans DT 
  INNER JOIN pcwitemtotal IT 
      ON DT.id = IT.deposittransid 
     AND ( DT.statecode IN ( :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8 ) 
       OR ( DT.statecode IN ( :9 ) AND IT.statecode = :10 ) )
  INNER JOIN pcwdepreceipt DR 
      ON DR.deposittransid = DT.id 
     AND DR.requesttime >= :11 
     AND DR.requesttime <= :12 
     AND DR.userid = :13
```

Comment: doesn't this change the query logic? the filtering in WHERE clause effectively made the join with pcwdepreceipt an INNER JOIN